# Reflection in a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ deﬁned by $x + 2y + 2z = 0$.

The projection of any vector $u$ on this plane is defined by the linear map $A$ such that $Au = \text{proj} _P(u)$.

$$A = 
       \begin{pmatrix}
        8/9 & -2/9 & -2/9 \\
        -2/9 & 5/9 & -4/9 \\
        -2/0 & -4/9 & 1/9 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $u$ be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $\textrm{refl}_P(u)$ be the reﬂection of $u$ of axis $P$. Find an expression for $\text{refl}_P(u)$ in terms of $u$ and $\text{proj}_P(u)$, and ﬁnd a matrix $B$ so that $Bu = \text{refl}_P(u)$ for any $u \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

I tried to find a standard matrix of reflection as there is one for projection. I couldn't do so. This question is a part of a bigger question and I had to find matrix A in earlier parts. I'm stuck here. I am not sure how to go about solving this.

Comment: Is it something to do with comparing with standard matrix of reflection? I don't think so. Wasn't particularly sure what to do.

Comment: Kindly, show your own efforts to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Consider a plane $\pi$. Since the dot product is non-degenerate on $\pi$, we have a direct decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $\pi \oplus \pi^{\perp}$: this means thst every vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ can be uniquely written as $v=v_1+v_2$, with $v_1 \in \pi$, $v_2 \in \pi^{\perp}$.

The reflection of axis $\pi$ is the unique linear application $\Sigma$ defined by

$$\Sigma_{\pi}^{\pi^{\perp}}: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R^3} \\  v=v_1+v_2 \mapsto v_1-v_2$$

Let $\textrm{id}$ be the identity operator, i.e. $\textrm{id}(w)=w$ for every $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Knowing that the projection $\Pi$ on $\pi$ instead maps $v=v_1+v_2$ to $v_1$, $\textrm{id}-\Pi$ is a function that maps $v$ to $v_2$. So, if we want to map $v$ to $v_1-v_2$, it suffices to subtract twice $(\textrm{id}-\Pi)(v)$ to $v$ itself, i.e.

$$\Sigma(v)= (\textrm{id}-2(\textrm{id}-\Pi))(v)=\color{red}{(2\Pi-\textrm{id})(v)}$$

This identity is true for the matrices of the linear operators involved, so we can conclude that the matrix $B$ of the reflection is

$$B=2A-\mathbb I= \\ 2\cdot
       \begin{pmatrix}
        8/9 & -2/9 & -2/9 \\
        -2/9 & 5/9 & -4/9 \\
        -2/9 & -4/9 & 1/9 \\
        \end{pmatrix} -\begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0& 1 \end {pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 7/9 & -4/9 & -4/9 \\ -4/9 & 1/9 & -8/9 \\ -4/9 & -8/9 & -7/9 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I get the perpendicular joining v and projection of v on u.

Comment: Should I then just multiply this perpendicular with 2 and get a reflection? I this correct ?

Comment: @AnirudhGangwal on the right track. You can't really multiply vectors, what do you mean? For instance, if you subtract to $v$ its projection on the $y$-axis, you obtain the projection on the $x$-axis. What happens if you subtract that vector again? Try drawing it.

Comment: I meant that I get a perpendicular vector (perpendicular to any line v in $R^2$, $proj_vu -u$. I do 2 (  $proj_vu -u$) to get reflection in line v.

Comment: Exactly. Actually, if you subtract $\text{proj}_y(v$*twice* from $v$ you obtain the reflection with respect to the $x$-axis, i.e. $\text{refl}_x(v)=v-2\text{proj}_y(v)$. Can you generalize this statement for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: I think it can be generalised. But I have a question, is it the same as reflx(v)= 2proj$_y$(v) - v ?

Comment: No. Writing $v=\text{proj}_x(v)+\text{proj}_y(v)$ should make it clearer: a reflection basically changes the sign of one of the projections, without varying the other.

Comment: What I meant was refl$_y$v = 2 proj$_y$v - v. Also, could you write the final equation involving just the line and the vector (you've used projection on x and y both above). This is confusing me a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: @AnirudhGangwal I edited with a full generalisation of the statement.